# How can I separate the logic into a separate component in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, components

How can I separate the logic into a separate component.

Testing.vue

```
data: function () {
   return {
     projects: []
   }
},
methods: {
 refreshProjects () {
   if (property.DEV_MODE) {
     console.log(this)
     let vm = this
     fetch('/api/Test/').then((response) => response.json()).then(json => {
            vm.projects = json
     }).catch(function () {
            vm.dataError = true
     })
   } else {
       this.projects = testJsonFile
     }
 }
}
```

this is my code, and I want to put this check if (property.DEV_MODE) on another component and only in this component to make fetch to server. For this reason maybe must first to import component in this component, check this condition and if is true to make fetch to server. Is there any way to make this? And what is better solution to separable logic not in this component?

Comment: it sounds like you want a global store, something like Vuex or an event bus, where . you can store property and then check its DEV_MODE status from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, vue will be run on the client-side(unless SSR) and so checking development mode on the vue frontend isn't the best.

Per the component-based design paradigm, it is advisable for a component to handle everything concerning it, including logic pertaining to it. Components must work like black boxes.